# ошибка в wp не удалось сохранить из-за 1 неверной настройки

Tags: wordpress

Не знаю, можно ли здесь выкладывать такие посты, но попытаюсь ))

Начал осваивать Wordpress, установил тему, всё вроде более менее настроил (локально, на Open Server)

нажимаю сохранить, и вылазит такая ошибка.
Проблема с сохранением email

Это защита у темы такая, или ошибка?
Как решить это вопрос?
Не хочется заново потом всё настраивать (((

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался
в консоли появился новый пункт, theme panel, там всё и настраивается